# jQuery toggle / click not working the way I want it

Tags: jquery, search, toggle

Check out my project at http://codepen.io/KyleMorgan49/full/ELqur

When I click on the button, it expands. But for some weird reason to close it, I have to click on the bottom of the box. I think the div#search-icon is moving down or shrinking, but I don't have any code that would make it do that. I'm confused. Can you take a minute to play around with this? Thanks!

Comment: Always put the relevant code and markup **in the question itself**, don't just link. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because your `#searchy-stuff` covers the middle of the icon (you can click the very top as well, not just the bottom to see it)

To fix it make the `#searchy-stuff` the same width as the input field

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LHpow)

Answer (score 0):

```
<p id="searchy-stuff" style="display: block;">
    <input type="text" id="search-input">
</p>
```

This section overlaps the icon after the first animation is done ... change your css and it will work. Actually no second click on icon is made.

Answer (score 0):

searchy-stuff is overlapping your search icon so click event is not triggered.

Add this css:

```
#searchy-stuff{pointer-events:none}
```